# socket.emit inside socket.on not working on client side Socket.io

Tags: node.js, socket.io

Client side code:-

```
<script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>

...snip...

var socket = io.connect( 'http://localhost:5000' );


socket.on('text_msg', function (data) {
    socket.emit('message', {txt:"test"});  //this is not working
    alert( data.msg );
});
```

Server Side Code looks like:-

```
const io = require('socket.io').listen(5000);
   io.emit('text_msg', {msg: 'Welcome you are now connected.'}); //this is working good

    // plain message - this never works 
    io.on('message', function(data){
        console.log("message : " + data.txt);   //No msg on console!
    });
});
```

Please help me in sending message from client script to the server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are emitting the text_msg event right as you start your socket server, and not when a connection is made. You should listen for the connection event on the server, and then emit the welcome message to the connected socket.

The message that the client sends to the server also won't be seen because you are not listening for it. You need to listen on each individual socket.

Your server-sided code should look like this:

```js
const io = require('socket.io').listen(5000);

io.on('connection', function (socket) {
    socket.emit('text_msg', {
        msg: 'Welcome you are now connected.'
    });

    socket.on('message', function(data) {
        console.log('message : ' + data.txt);
    });
});
```

Comment: After replacing the server code with above code... Neither io.emit nor io.on is working now..Please help!

Comment: I solved my issue as I'm using socket inside another callback of Mosca.js `moscaServer.on('published', function(client) {` . Anyone facing similar issue please define your socket code outside these types of callbacks. Thanks!